# Must jpa key be the same as database key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have the following key in the database:

- A
- B

And an unique constraint on column C.

Am I forced to define my jpa key as a composite key or I could also define it as C, being that unique?

Comment: No, you don't need to define your  column C as composite key in your Entity class. Ultimately is is required  when you don't have your table already made in your database and you need to make table according to your  Entity class if your `persistence` property.
Database will do the job for you even you just define  it  as C

Comment: I have a couple of questions.
-What is a key? Primary key? Foreign key? Hash key?
-What do you mean by defining jpa key? Do you mean marking field with `@Id` annotation on entity class?

Comment: Yes I mean @Id as key